# How to remove a key/value pair from a nested hash in params?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I would like to remove a key/value from a nested hash in my params.

My params are:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "q"=>{"upward_trending"=>"", "downward_trending"=>"", "name_cont"=>"test", "category_id_in"=>["1", ""], "country_eq"=>"", "end_date_gteq"=>"", "end_date_lteq"=>""}, "commit"=>"Filter", "type"=>"Dailyd
eal"}
```

I would like to remove `name_cont` from the `q` hash.

I am able to remove the full hash by doing:

```
request.query_parameters.except(:q)
```

or

```
params.except(:q)
```

But everytime I try anything like:

```
except(:q[:name_cont])
except("name_cont")
except([:q][:name_cont])
```

I get errors.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try

```
request.query_parameters[:q].except(:name_cont)
# or
params[:q].except(:name_cont)
```

You can use `except!` also if you want in-place modification.

Comment: Which method you used? except or except!